# Multiple Weight based Pricing for a product in codeigniter using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have made a shopping cart website using ajax and Codeigniter. The products is added to cart without the page load when the button add to cart is clicked. I was displaying single net weight for the product, but now i have changed it to multiple netweight for the same product. but add to cart is not working for the product which has multiple netweight. because i am not getting the logic to send the data of a selected dropdown list.

```
<section class="regular slider">
<?php 
foreach($todays_offers as $offer)
{   
    if(!empty($offer))
    {
        $product_id=$offer->id;
        $product_name=$offer->product_name;
        $image=$offer->image;
        $price=$offer->mrp;
        $our_price=$offer->retail_price;  
        $brand=$offer->brand;
        $pro_quantity=$offer->stock;
        $gst=$offer->gst;
        $stock=$offer->stock;
    }
?>
    <div class="product-container col-xs-12" style="">
        <div class="product-left">
            <div class="product-thumb">
                <a class="product-img" href="#">
                    <img src='<?php echo base_url("images/$image")?> ' alt="<?php echo $product_name?>" >
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-right">
            <div class="product-brand ">
                <?php echo ucfirst($brand); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="product-name " style="height: 40px;overflow: hidden;line-height:17px;">
                <a href="#"><?php echo $product_name ?></a>
            </div>                                                      

<?php
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM materials where product_name='".$product_name."' ORDER BY retail_price ASC";
    $query1 = $this->db->query($sql);
    $rowCount="SELECT * FROM materials where product_name='$product_name'";
    $query2 = $this->db->query($rowCount);
    if (!empty($query1)) 
    {
        if ($query2->num_rows() > 1) 
        {
            echo "<select name='netweight' id='netweight' onchange='ItemSelected(this)'>";  
            foreach ($query1->result() as $row) 
            {
                $net = $row->packing; 
                $retail_price = $row->retail_price; 
?>
            <option id="<?php echo $row->id;?>" value="<?php echo $net;?>" ><?php echo $net .' - Rs. '. $retail_price?> </option>
    <?php 
            }
            echo "</select>";       

        }
        else
        {
            $net_weight=$offer->packing;
            echo "<span>$net_weight</span>";
        }

    }
    ?>
            <div class="price-box">
                <span class="product-price"> <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo   $our_price ?></span>
                <?php 
                if($our_price<$price)
                { 
                ?>
                <span class="product-price-old">MRP <i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo  $price ?></span>
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-4 pad-0"> <input type="number"  value="1" min="1" max="10"  name="quantity"  class="form-control quantity" id="<?php echo  $product_id ?>" /></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5 pad-0">
                <div class="product-button">


                <?php 
                if($pro_quantity>0)
                {
                ?>        
                    <a class="button-radius btn-add-cart add_cart" type="button" title="Add to Cart" name="add_cart"  data-netweight="<?php echo $net_weight ?>" data-image="<?php echo $image ?>" data-productname= "<?php echo $product_name ?>" data-price="<?php echo $price?>" data-productid="<?php echo $product_id ?>" data-brand="<?php echo $brand ?>"data-gst="<?php echo $gst ?>" data-stock="<?php echo $stock ?>" >add<span class="icon"></span></a>
               <?php 
                }
                else
                {                                                                               
                  echo "<span class='label label-danger'>Out of stock</span>";
                }   

                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
}
?>
</section>
```

ajax code

```
$('.add_cart').click(function() {    
    var product_id = $(this).data("productid");    
    var product_name = $(this).data("productname");
    var product_price = $(this).data("price");
    var net = $(this).closest(".netweight").val();
    alert(net);
    var image=$(this).data("image");
    var brand=$(this).data("brand");
    var gst=$(this).data("gst");
    var stock=$(this).data("stock");
    var quantity = $('#' + product_id).val();  
    if(quantity != '' && quantity > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>shopping_cart/add",
            method:"POST",
            data:{product_id:product_id, product_name:product_name, product_price:product_price, quantity:quantity,net:net,image:image,brand:brand,gst:gst,stock:stock },
            success:function(data)
            {
                 $.alert(product_name, {
                        title: 'Success product is added to cart',
                        closeTime: 6 * 1000,
                        autoClose: true,

                    });
             $('#cart_details').html(data);

             $('#' + product_id).val(1);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please Enter quantity");
    }
});
```

I just want send the selected data with id to the cart
[image: this is how it displays]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you dont pick up the value from your selected option and you dont set a value at all.

You should post your entire list item partial here - because i need the ancestor of the select element `netweight`

a possible solution could be :

add a value field to your option element like (be aware - i don't know your desired value, so i took `$row->net` instead)

```
<option id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" value="<?=$row->net; ?>">
    <?php echo $net .' - Rs. '. $retail_price?>               
</option>
```

and of course in your js function you have to change your `net` Variable accordingly `$(this).closest(".netweight").val()` might not work - because i need the correct ancestor - so pls post your entire view here.

```
$('.add_cart').click(function () 
{
    var product_id = $(this).data("productid");
    var product_name = $(this).data("productname");

    var product_price = $(this).data("price");
    var net = $(this).closest(".product-right").find(".netweight").val();
    var image = $(this).data("image");
    var brand = $(this).data("brand");
    var gst = $(this).data("gst");
    var stock = $(this).data("stock");
    var quantity = $('#' + product_id).val();


    if (quantity != '' && quantity > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>shopping_cart/add",
            method: "POST",
            data: {product_id: product_id, product_name: product_name, product_price: product_price, quantity: quantity, net: net, image: image, brand: brand, gst: gst, stock: stock},
            success: function (data)
            {
                $.alert(product_name, {
                    title: 'Success product is added to cart',
                    closeTime: 6 * 1000,
                    autoClose: true,

                });
                $('#cart_details').html(data);

                $('#' + product_id).val(1);
            }
        });
    } 
    else
    {
        alert("Please Enter quantity");
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for your great effort. I have tried with the closest jquery function but its not working. i have updated my above code, i need your help.

Comment: var net = $(this).closest(".product-right").find(".netweight").val();     in  this what is .product-right. is it a class? but i have no where used product-right class

Comment: this is the error i am getting if the add to cart to clicked if that product has singlr netweight "Message: Undefined index: net"

Comment: i am getting this alert if i click add to cart that has multiple dropdown "please enter quantity"

Comment: no offense men, i wrote "add a value field to your option element like (be aware - i don't know your desired value, so i took $row->net instead)" - its obvious that `$row->net` is undefined - i simply don't know which value you want - so you've to replace it with your desired value

Comment: closest(".product-right") where did u find .product-right?

Comment: show @your view there is a line starting with `<div class="product-right">`